Add a new outbound call to an existing conversation
I am trying to add a new call to an existing conversation. When I use the 'CreateCallAsync' method from the Voice API (dotnet SDK), the call is created in a new conversation, regardless of which ConversationUUID is passed in the NCCO object.
Once the call is answered, it is transferred to the correct conversation. However, until then, I have no access to this call (e.g., I would like to close the outgoing call if the last participant of the conversation leaves before the newcomer joins, etc.).
Is there any way to force the intended ConversationUUID or transfer the call manually?
I tried to update the call immediately after it is created but got a bad request error from Vonage API. I also tried to create the call with connect action instead of conversation action, but again, resulted in Vonage API error.
